# How prove this $\sum_{t|n}(d(t))^3=\left(\sum_{t|n}d(t)\right)^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, divisor-sum, multiplicative-function

show that
$$\sum_{t|n}(d(t))^3=\left(\sum_{t|n}d(t)\right)^2$$

where $d(n)$ is the number of positive divisors of $n$.

see this have simaler
$$1^3+2^3+\cdots+n^3=\left(1+2+\cdots+n\right)^2$$

maybe this have something to do?

and How prove this nice equation.Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $n = p^k$ is a prime power, we have

$$\sum_{t\mid n} d(t)^3 = \sum_{j=0}^k (j+1)^3 = \left(\sum_{j=0}^k (j+1)\right)^2 = \left(\sum_{t\mid n} d(t)\right)^2$$

by the "similar" identity. For general $n$, use the multiplicativity of $d(\cdot)^m$, that is, for coprime $a,b$ we have $d(ab) = d(a)d(b)$, which becomes

$$\sum_{t\mid n} d(t)^3 = \prod_{p\mid n} \sum_{j= 0}^{v_p(n)} (j+1)^3 = \prod_{p\mid n} \left(\sum_{j=0}^{v_p(n)} (j+1)\right)^2 = \left(\sum_{t\mid n} d(t)\right)^2$$

since for a multiplicative function $f$, also the sum $F(n) = \sum_{t\mid n} f(t)$ is multiplicative.